# Using case_when within mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `case_when` within `mutate_at`, as in the following example:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(vs, am),
            .funs = funs(case_when(
              . %in% c(1,0,9) ~ TRUE
              . %in% c(2,20,200) ~ FALSE
              TRUE ~ as.character(.)
            )))
```

alternative version using **`. =`** in `funs()` call also does not work.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(vs, am),
            .funs = funs(. = case_when(
              . %in% c(1, 0, 9) ~ TRUE
              . %in% c(2, 20, 200) ~ FALSE
              TRUE ~ as.character(.)
            )))
```

## Desired results

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(vs, am),
         .funs = funs(ifelse(. %in% c(1, 0, 9), TRUE, FALSE)))
```

*`FALSE` could be replaced with second `ifelse()` call, which I didn't include for brevity.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We need `,` to separate each case. Also, if we are keeping the last option as `character`, then the `TRUE/FALSE` should be character as well.  No mixing of types

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(vs, am),
        .funs = funs(. = case_when(
          . %in% c(1, 0, 9) ~ TRUE,
          . %in% c(2, 20, 200) ~ FALSE,
          TRUE ~ TRUE
        )))
```

---

If we need to make `character` class and also to return the column as character if either of the two cases are not correct, perhaps

```
mtcars %>%
 mutate_at(.vars = vars(vs, am),
        .funs = funs(. = case_when(
          . %in% c(1, 0, 9) ~ "Yes",
          . %in% c(2, 20, 200) ~ "No",
          TRUE ~ as.character(.)
        )))
```

Comment: so the issue is with `as.character(.)` at the end, as this what seems to break the pipe?

Comment: @Konrad You also had `,` problem

Comment: Ah, yes a typo.

Comment: What if you need to put in information from another column into case_when. Is it impossible then?

Comment: @Dan Did you meant something like `mtcars %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(vs, am), .funs = funs(case_when(mtcars$gear ==4| . %in% 1 ~"Yes", TRUE ~ as.character(.))))`