# dplyr mutate_at and case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to identify variables with starts_with() and then perform a case_when mutation.

For example, let's say I want to do the equivalent of:

```
mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg == 21.0] <- 5; mtcars
```

My attempt:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with("mpg")),
    funs(. = case_when(
      . == 21.0 ~ 5,
      TRUE ~ .
    ))
  )
```

What am I doing wrong? The dplyr documentation doesn't seem to have many examples of mutate_at/mutate_each ([this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/good-explanation-of-how-to-use-scoped-verbs/178/2) seems to have the same complaint), so I have a hard time with these functions. Maybe I am not looking in the right place?

I'm aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887950/using-case-when-within-mutate-at) but wasn't able to find a solution in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`funs` creates a list of functions, when you do `funs(. = ...)`, it creates named functions with name of `.`, and this leads to new column(s) being generated with either the name of `.` if you have only one column, or the name with suffix of `.` if you have more than one column to mutate; If you need to overwrite the original column, simply leave the functions unnamed by directly passing the anonymous function to `funs`. In your case, removing `. =` in `funs` should work;

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with("mpg")),
    funs(case_when(
      . == 21.0 ~ 5,
      TRUE ~ .
    ))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That makes sense. Is this specific to dplyr or just R syntax?

Comment: It's a `dplyr` syntax and more specifically related to `mutate/summarize` `at/if/all/` and `funs`.

Comment: that's what I thought. Do you happen to know of good reference material for this kind of thing? I often have questions about scoped dplyr verb syntax and am not sure where to look

Comment: If you use `Rstudio`, you can do `?mutate_at` for instance, read the docs there and try out the examples below. Your case for instance is covered by the last example where the comment says *Function names will be included if .funs has names or multiple inputs*.