# How to efficiently create column with conditional variable names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For some time now, I've been creating very long 20+ line renaming `case_when()` statements to create new columns based on values of one subsequent column.

Right now, it looks something like this:

```
tibble(x = rep(1:3, 3), 
       y = case_when(x == 1 ~ "good", 
                     x == 2 ~ "good", 
                     x == 3 ~ "bad", 
                     TRUE ~ as.character(x)))
```

But for long lists of variables, it's completely inefficient to rename / create new cols like this. One instance has 4 potential assignment (col `y` above) across 3-6 variables, so a lot of repetition.

Any source / ideas on how to make this process more efficient?

Comment: Use `mutate_at()` along with `case_when` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887950/using-case-when-within-mutate-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for. I am applying your classification on 4 columns at the same time using `mutate_at`:

library(dplyr)

```
tibble(x1 = rep(1:3, 3),
       x2 = rep(3:1, 3),
       x3 = rep(1:3, each = 3),
       x4 = rep(3:1, each = 3)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")), 
            list(y = ~case_when(. %in% 1:2 ~ "good",
                               . == 3 ~ "bad", 
                               TRUE ~ as.character(.))))
    # A tibble: 9 x 8
     x1    x2    x3    x4 x1_y  x2_y  x3_y  x4_y 
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     3     1     3 good  bad   good  bad  
2     2     2     1     3 good  good  good  bad  
3     3     1     1     3 bad   good  good  bad  
4     1     3     2     2 good  bad   good  good 
5     2     2     2     2 good  good  good  good 
6     3     1     2     2 bad   good  good  good 
7     1     3     3     1 good  bad   bad   good 
8     2     2     3     1 good  good  bad   good 
9     3     1     3     1 bad   good  bad   good
```